# How to display a div AFTER redirecting to next page?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on my FIRST webapp, using jsp, javascript, etc. The initial page is the "login.jsp". Inside that page, there is a link to the sign up page and when the user submit the registration form, through a Servlet, he is sent back to the login page. But i wish a success alert to appear inside the login page at the same time the page loads.

I don't know the exact way to make this possible. I thought about setting a request attribute like a "notifier" in the servlet, so the login page knows whether the user comes from sign up or not. But then, i'm not sure how to "read" that attribute. I've already tried using javascript, jsp, etc. etc. Nothing worked for me.
Besides, I don't know if i should redirect using RequestDispatcher.forward() and set the notifier as a Session attribute. (Here i have another problem, the login page's stylesheet doesn't load.)

This is some of the sign up page:

```
//....
<form action="/servlet/UpdateUser" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" class="form" role="form">
//....        
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block signup-btn" type="submit" name="signup">Create my account</button>
</form>
//....
```

Some of the servlet:

```
 //servlet
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        if (req.getParameter("signup") != null) {
            User user = new User();
            //user setters and register
            //..
            //Should i use (?):
            //req.setAttribute("SignUp", true);
        } //..
        //rest of the servlet
        resp.sendRedirect("../login.jsp");
    }
```

Some of login page:

```
//Rest of Login Page
//Here is something i've tried.
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var b = <%request.getAttribute("SignUp");%>;
        if (b) document.getElementById('success').style.display = 'block';
        else document.getElementById('success').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
//Rest of Login Page
<body>
 //..
   <div class="alert alert-success" id="success">
       <strong>Success!</strong> You can now login.
   </div>
//..
</body>
//Rest of Login Page
```

PD: It's my first question here.

Answer (score 0):

Good job working on your first webapp!

You can definitely communicate weather user just registered or not through a request attribute. The thing is, if the page `login.jsp` is located inside `WEB-INF`, you'll have to use `request.getRequestDispathcer("../login.jsp").forward(request, response)`.
If it's in the root, you can use `resp.sendRedirect("../login.jsp");`.

The commented code where you set the request parameter SignUp looks fine.

Other thing is your inappropriate use of scriptlets. Namely, when you want to assign a value to `var b`, you need to use `<%=` (compared to `<%` that you used) to return a value.
Even better, you can use *expression language* - just put `${SignUp}` after `var b =`(try to type attribute labels in all lowercase in future).

The rest of JS looks fine.

Comment: I used `req.setAttribute("signup", true)` and then `req.getRequestDispathcer("../login.jsp").forward(req, resp)`, but the problem is on the reading of the attribute in login.jsp, besides the first time, the attribute doesn't exist. `<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var su = ${signup};
            if (su === true) {
                document.getElementById('success').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('success').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    </script>`

Comment: the div is being displayed anyway.

Comment: You should try passing a string as an attribute `req.setAttribute("signup", "true")` and then comparing it like `if(su === "true")`.
Note that you can send a whole object as an attribute as well, and then access that objects' fields using `${objectName.fieldName}`.